# get count in linq query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

i want to get count in linq query its work fine without comparing date in where condition but after comparing date it gives exception.

```
public static IList GetAllCategoryData()
{
     using (var objEntity = new BlueCouponEntities())
     {
       return (from TBL in objEntity.CategoryMasters.AsEnumerable()
                 let IIT = TBL.CategoryImageTransactions
                 select new
                 {
                 TBL.CategoryID,
                 TBL.CategoryName,
                 CategoryCount = objEntity.OfferCategoryMasters.Where(Lg => Lg.CategoryID == TBL.CategoryID && Lg.OfferMaster.EndDate > DateTime.Now.Date).Count(),
                 }
             ).ToList();
     }
}
```

Error is : The specified type member ;Date; is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: The type Date is not supported in SQL-to-Entities.

Comment: @WicherVisser there is no type `Date` in the .NET standard library, it's an instance property on the `DateTime` struct, returning a `DateTime` with the same date as the current instance, but where the time is `00:00:00`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` to get the Date part of DateTime

```
using (var objEntity = new BlueCouponEntities())
{
    return (from TBL in objEntity.CategoryMasters.AsEnumerable()
                 let IIT = TBL.CategoryImageTransactions
                 select new
                 {
                 TBL.CategoryID,
                 TBL.CategoryName,
                 CategoryCount = objEntity.OfferCategoryMasters.Where(Lg => Lg.CategoryID == TBL.CategoryID && Lg.OfferMaster.EndDate > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now)).Count(),
                 }
             ).ToList();
}
```

Since DateTime.Now is Constant at the moment, you could also write this

```
 using (var objEntity = new BlueCouponEntities())
 {
     DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date;
     return (from TBL in objEntity.CategoryMasters.AsEnumerable()
                 let IIT = TBL.CategoryImageTransactions
                 select new
                 {
                 TBL.CategoryID,
                 TBL.CategoryName,
                 CategoryCount = objEntity.OfferCategoryMasters.Where(Lg => Lg.CategoryID == TBL.CategoryID && Lg.OfferMaster.EndDate > now).Count(),
                 }
             ).ToList();   
}
```

Comment: The second example is going to solve a rare issue where the query is run spanning midnight.

Comment: this is an overly complicated way of doing it. the issue is that `Date` isn't a recognized property in L2E, but there is nothing preventing you from just assigning `DateTime.Now.Date` to a local variable and using that in the query instead, as in @BappyDatta's answer.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the Count() function. As the exception says, its 
a DateTime problem. Use [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220143(v=vs.113).aspx) (`EntityFunctions.TruncateTime` is deprecated since EF6)

```
public static IList GetAllCategoryData()
{
     using (var objEntity = new BlueCouponEntities())
     {
       return (from TBL in objEntity.CategoryMasters.AsEnumerable()
                 let IIT = TBL.CategoryImageTransactions
                 select new
                 {
                 TBL.CategoryID,
                 TBL.CategoryName,
                 CategoryCount = objEntity.OfferCategoryMasters.Where(Lg => Lg.CategoryID == TBL.CategoryID && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(Lg.OfferMaster.EndDate) > EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.Date)).Count(),
                 }
             ).ToList();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines:

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

Then use ***today*** instead of ***DateTime.Now.Date*** into linq query.